# Want to add anchor html tag for each http/https hyperlinks in my GWT application (Java 7)

Tags: java, javascript, regex, gwt, java-7

In a GWT application (with Java 7) I want to add anchor html tag for each http/https links I have in a String variable.

It worked in embed mode but not in production.

```
private String clearTextContent(String txt) {
    txt = txt.replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
    txt = txt.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");

    txt = txt.replaceAll("\n", "");
    txt = txt.replaceAll("\\|", "<br/>");

    // Display Link for URLs
    txt = txt.replaceAll("(\\A|\\s)((http|https|ftp|mailto):\\S+)(\\s|\\z)", "$1<a target='_blank' href='$2'>$2</a>$4"); 
}
```

I have tried this too but don't works:

```
    String URLregexp = "(^|\\s)((http|https):\\S+)(\\s|$)";
    txt = txt.replaceAll(URLregexp, "$1<a target='_blank' href='$2'>$2</a>$4");
```

Example that I want:

input:

```
Hello|http:///www.google.com|... That's it!
```

output:

```
Hello|<a target='_blank' href='http:///www.google.com'>http:///www.google.com</a>|... That's it!
```

I have read that in embed mode GWT use the javascript regular expression and in production, the java one.

Have you a tips in order to fix my issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed HTML in a widget, not all widget are able to do that, since > or < and & will be replaced by their ASCII counterparts. 
You need to use SafeHtml and a widget that can display it. For instance you could do it with a [`<g:HTML ui:field="htmlBlock">`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html)

You have several ways to generate SafeHtml that you can put in your widget. For instance use

```
SafeHtml safeHtml = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(myCodeAsString);
htmlBlock.setHtml(safeHtml);
```

So check in which kind of widget your String variable is displayed with and switch to another widget if necessary.